# Finding old files using NSMetadataQuery

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I need solution for osx 10.6.7+. I trying to solve problem of searching "old" files on the disk. Old Files I mean files which early 1 year.
I've created NSPredicate but NSMetadataQuery returns nothing

```
NSPredicate * fileTypePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"file_type == \"audio\""];
NSPredicate * accessDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K <= %@",  @"kMDItemAccessedDates", timeYearBefore];
return [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[fileTypePredicate, accessDatePredicate]];
```

Instead of kMDItemAccessedDates also I used acess_date but also without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, I don't know why you expect “file_type” to be a supported metadata property.

There are two properties for an item's content type. One is `kMDItemContentType`, which is the immediate type of the item's content (generally as determined by its filename extension). The other is `kMDItemContentTypeTree`, which is an array of that type and every one of its ancestors.

To find audio files, you want to find items whose `kMDItemContentTypeTree` is equal to `kUTTypeAudio`. (Yes, equality testing will work for this, even though you really want to test whether the array contains the type. Try it in Terminal: `mdfind 'kMDItemContentTypeTree == public.audio'`)

In your code, you should use a two-parameter format string, just like you have for the second predicate, but with `==` as the operator: `@"%K == %@"` For the parameters, pass `kMDItemContentTypeTree` (the key) and `kUTTypeAudio` (the value—in this case, content type—you're looking for).

---

As for the second one, I can't find any mention of `kMDItemAccessedDates` anywhere other [exactly one other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357577/nspredicates-for-nsmetadataquery-to-match-kmditemaccesseddates-array-contain/14373562#14373562). I think the author of that question might have made that key up for his custom Spotlight importer; you can't expect to find it on a stock OS X system.

You might try `kMDItemLastUsedDate` instead. (Don't write it as a string literal, in `@"…"`—just have `kMDItemLastUsedDate` without any quotes around it or an @ in front of it.)

Comment: Thank you. I was needed to postpone solving issues. Since last time I've tried kMDItemLastUsedDate too. As a expected kMDItemLastUsedDate i have used result of command mdls of file where kMDItemLastUsedDate was (2014-02-24 10:24:32). In that case predicate was http://pastebin.com/PtCkPHdP and I found 0 results :( Any ideas?

Comment: @toohtik: Are you sure you have a date object (`date` is not `nil`)?

Comment: yes I'm sure. After printing NSPredicate i got something like this: kMDItemLastUsedDate == CAST(414931838.000000, "NSDate") Also I've used date exactly in mdls output. If you have a bit free time check my source please http://cl.ly/1I2C253U230b My osx 10.9. Thanks a lot!